# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is making system very slow in (Compact framework 6.0) (.net 2.0) C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, compact-framework, threadpool

I am using Threadpool for backend processing in window smart application having compact framework 6.0 and .net freamwork 2.0. 
I have tried both ways of calling like

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback (SyncTbl));
```

or

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(SyncTbl);
```

but in both situation application is becoming very slow due to these processes.

I also can't use `BackgroundWorker` class because my application is developed in .net 2.0.

Kindly give me some suggestions.

Comment: And how often do you call this? And what is SyncTbl doing?

Comment: I am using PDA device and saving some record in local Compact edition database then syncTable passes data from local to remote database using threadpool, i am calling this function when i save any record, before that i was just saving data into the central DB using a web service which was also taking too much time so i used it as back end prepossessing,

now syncTbl calls web service in the back end

Answer (score 0):

Threadpool threads will not be released unless there is lack of resource. I would recommend to use SetMaxThreads to set up the maximum number of threads in the pool. Or for compact framework, using Thread class will be also considerable.